# Get Access Token Using C#, Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get the access token for the feed.Below is a code, i used to get the access token.

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            string postString = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&grant_type=password", "userName", "pwd");

            string url = "http://example.net/Token";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            UTF8Encoding utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = utfenc.GetBytes(postString);


            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
                Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();//parse token from result
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return "";
        }
```

The error below

```
"An error occurred while sending the request. The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The server name or address could not be resolved"
```

is throwing while it executes the below code

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
```

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: There is no tag for Windows-phone-10. I don't have reputation to create a new tag.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Thank you for the reply. Can u guide what mistake i have done

Comment: This synchronous call in .CS side.

Comment: You should replace "http://example.net/Token" with some real address for which you want to get a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you are using `POST` request

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        string postString = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&grant_type=password", "userName", "pwd");
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "FeedURL");
                request1.Content = new StringContent(postString);
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request1);
                var result1 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result1 = Regex.Replace(result1, "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
                var rootObject1 = JObject.Parse(result1);
                string accessToken = rootObject1["access_token"].ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```